# Are non-dangerous spiders (to humans) dangerous to dogs?

Tags: dogs, health, physiology, arachnids

I am fortunate to live an area were we have few spiders that have venom potent enough to be dangerous to humans, however, my yard seems to support a significant spider population of various species, so I am wondering if I need to be worried or not.

To clarify a bit, obviously weight (of the dog) is going to have a major influence on this so I want to try to avoid that part of the conversation.  I'm more concerned about physiology.

Is the physiology of dogs similar enough to humans that the impact of a spiders venom would be the same in dogs as it is in humans?  Or would the venom from a spider affect a dog differently than a human?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, yes.

Some more details: you will want to look up the spiders endemic to your area and their effects on dogs. Smaller dogs are obviously more vulnerable, but many spiders have venom that is harmless to some species and lethal to others.

Even more detail: I grew up in Australia, where it's common knowledge that redback spiders while not lethal (but quite painful) to healthy adults can kill small children and small dogs or cats.

To be sure of your dog's safety, you may find the breed matters - like any animal they're most likely to be resistant to the venom of snakes and spiders endemic to the area where their breed originated.